# Add long text item in ListBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox

Is there any way to add a long text value to an ASP.NET Listbox control and because the text is too long it can be split into multiple listbox items so that the entire text is shown (in javascript/jquery) ?

Comment: can you try this @VivianeAbitbol? `ListBoxItem lstBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
lstBoxItem.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Looooooong Text" + "\n", TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow };`

Comment: but how can I  do that in  javascript/jquery?

Comment: you can do this in C# itself. no need to javascript/jquery

Comment: you can use a tooltip to show the long text or wrap the listbox in a div and set the horizontal scroll by setting the overflow property of the div

Comment: @Sushil I would like to send you my program so that you can tell me what I'm doing wrong. How can I chat with you? p.s: I'm on facebook

Comment: Hi @VivianeAbitbol. are you on LinkedIn?

Comment: can you give me ur email address?

Comment: ok. will send u a msg on facebook. check ur other messages folder

Comment: thank you soo sooo much!!!! :) :) :) :)

Comment: you're most welcome @VivianeAbitbol :)